# NWListener: Is an applicationService discoverable?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to browse peers using NWBrowser/NWListener, but the browser only sees peers when using `.bonjour`, not `.applicationService`. Apple's TicTacToe example also uses 'bonjour' to find peers, and 'applicationService' for the actual protocol. Is it not possible to browse 'applicationService' listeners directly?

Listener

```
let params = NWParameters.tcp // using .applicationService results in 'Network is down' error
let listener = try NWListener(using: params)
listener.service = NWListener.Service(applicationService: "MyApp")
listener.stateUpdateHandler = { ... }
listener.newConnectionHandler = { ... }
listener.start(queue: .main)
```

Browser

```
let params = NWParameters()
let browser = NWBrowser(for: .applicationService(name: "MyApp"), using: params)
browser.stateUpdateHandler = { newState in
    print('browser:', newState)
}
browser.browseResultsChangedHandler = { ... }
browser.start(queue: .main)
```

The listener and browser both reach 'ready' status, but the browser does not find any peers.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that this 'applicationService' requires the DeviceDiscoveryUI to be engaged:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicediscoveryui/devicepicker

I haven't worked out the details yet, but I'm assuming this is how some apps communicate with themselves over WLAN.

Comment: I'm not familiar with DeviceDiscovery, it's only for tvOS.